# How to attach c console application to running process

Tags: c, windows

I want to attach a C program to working process so i can hook it and work on it's memory

Note: I'm not talking about DLL i want my console application to attach and edit on memory and work it self out.

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're looking for the [Windows Debugging API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms679295%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), specifically the functions [`DebugActiveProcess()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms679295%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), [`WriteProcessMemory()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681674%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) etc.

There are some complete examples available at [debuginfo.com](http://www.debuginfo.com/examples/dbgexamples.html) (I haven't looked at them in detail).

Comment: well that's helpful, the only question is may i relay on this API using C Programming language? as i see the examples is in C++ and I'm afraid that it doesn't support C?!

Comment: It's standard Windows API and is callable from C.